# Substr on date oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I had an argument with my teacher that he said that Its not acceptable to use `substring` on date format column in `oracle`. Because `substr` should use on string-s and not on date. Whats your opinion on this?

The tast was that:

```
Lists those guest who were in one of our apartment at his/her birthday
```

The query was this:

```
select *
from ACCOMODATION.GUEST
    JOIN ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION ON (USERNAME = GUEST_FK) 
where to_date(CONCAT(SUBSTR(ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION.ARRIVAL,0,2), substr(BDAY, 3, length( BDAY ))))
      between ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION.ARRIVAL and ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION.LEAVE ;
```

`ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION.ARRIVAL`, `ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION.LEAVE` and `BDAY` is date

Comment: What is the datatype of your columns `ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION.ARRIVAL` and `ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION.LEAVE`?

Comment: Tip of today: table aliases. (Makes the query easier to write and to read.)

Comment: By the way, your teacher is absolutely, completely, 100% right!!!!

Comment: Use TO_CHAR instead of substr.

Comment: Your teacher is right, though you're implicitly converting the date to a string to be able to do the substr at all - look what happens when you change your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT. Incidentally, also consider what happens if the reservation spans new year (arrival is 2016, departure is 2017); and if the guest's birthday is February 29th.

Comment: Thanks for responds. And anyone has better solution ( my teacher wrote 2 query, because of if someone stay at the apartment 2016.12.25-2017.01.07 or something like this, the between doesnt works) or a TO_CHAR  is enough ( but i think it wont be enough because of feb 29 )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments, try to_char for dates. If stored as char already, then you've got bigger problems

```
select AG.*, AR.*
from ACCOMODATION.GUEST AG
INNER JOIN ACCOMODATION.RESERVATION  AR
  ON (USERNAME = GUEST_FK) 
where (to_char(AR.LEAVE, 'MMDD') > to_char(AR.ARRIVAL, 'MMDD') 
      and to_char(AG.BDAY, 'MMDD') 
          between to_char(AR.ARRIVAL, 'MMDD') 
                  and to_char(AR.LEAVE, 'MMDD')) -- for those who did not stay over the new year
or (to_char(AR.LEAVE, 'MMDD') < to_char(AR.ARRIVAL, 'MMDD') -- for those who stayed over new year
    and (to_char(AG.BDAY, 'MMDD') >=  to_char(AR.ARRIVAL, 'MMDD')
         or to_char(AG.BDAY, 'MMDD') <= to_char(AR.LEAVE, 'MMDD')))
```

Comment: Yes firstly i taught something like this, but i felt like there is an easier way to solve it. However i was wrong.